# Movie about a game show where the prize is a new life

Tags: story-identification, movie

Some years ago I watched a movie I can't remember the title of. The action is kind of blurry as well, but I seem to remember some kind of 'game show' where the contestant got a 'new life'. The main character escapes through some service tunnels, I think, and eventually ends up in a city nearby... or something..? Does it ring any bells, anyone?

Comment: I think this needs a more descriptive title. Perhaps "Movie about a game show where the prize is a new life". Also, what does "new life" mean? A new identity? Longevity? A means to escape death once? A Timelord regeneration? Clarifying that would probably help. Also, do you remember anything about the game show?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not a lot to go on there, but it puts me in mind of [The Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Island_(2005_film)): there's the 'competition' where winners get to leave to go to the Island (but actually are to be used for spare parts), Lincoln and Jordan (Ewan McGregor and Scarlett Johansson) escape the facility through service tunnels and end up in a city.

Comment: Ah, The Island, that's the name. Thank you PhilPursglove, and thanks to you too, ywhately, for a great tip on something to wath in the future ;-)

Answer (score 1):

That's almost certainly "Logan's Run".  There was a short-lived television show based on the film, too, but the film is what you're going to probably want to see, especially if you don't remember it very well (it had some really nightmarish plot twists to the elements you remember that you might not have appreciated if you saw it as a kid).

Comment: What would the "game show" the OP described be in Logan's Run?

Comment: The "game show" part is the Renewal Ceremony:  the characters have a "life clock" in their hands that turns red when they get too old, and they report for Renewal for a chance to live longer.  The people who try to escape from this are "runners", and Logan's job is to hunt them down when they run - Logan's life clock has run out, and the movie is about Logan's "run".

Comment: I find it a stretch to call the Renewal Ceremony a game show. Sure it's a spectacle, but it doesn't involve a contest of any sort, which I think is necessary for something to be called that.

Comment: I can see how the OP would have remembered it as a "game show" - the movie would have been quite disorienting for a young viewer.  Since the scene involved the renewal ceremony being performed before cheering audiences, with 'winners' supposedly getting renewed, I can see where the original poster would make a connection to a game show.

Comment: I can try including a video of the "Carousel" renewal ceremony from "Logan's Run", to see if it rings any bells for the OP: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LSUAAKFLoL0

Comment: It's probably also worth mentioning that Logan and other characters do escape from the domed city through its service tunnels, and find their way to a city outside the dome.  From what I remember of the television show, it picks up from there, following the characters as they travel from one post-apocalyptic dystopia to another, but they do at least make it to one other city by the end of the original film.

Answer (score 1):

I do not remember the exact actions of him escaping the (game show) limbo but [*What goes around* (Sorte kugler)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1363140/) is a Danish movie with a game show where the protagonist has to revisit events in his life and improve his terrible and selfish actions he did back then. Good revisits are rewarded with "white balls" and bad revisits are rewarded with "black balls". Filling the bar with white balls will give him a new chance of life.

Answer (score 1):

While the question's marked as answered, if others are looking for the same sort of film, I'd mention [The Running Man (1987)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0093894/), where Arnold Schwarzenegger plays Ben Richards, a cop who was blamed for a massacre which wasn't his fault.

He's sent to prison and breaks out with some other inmates. He tries to escape but the woman whom he dragged into his plan turns him over to the authorities. Damon Killian, who is the host of THE RUNNING MAN a game show wherein convicted felons are given the chance to run to freedom but have to elude the stalkers; men who hunt them down and kill them.